# Angular 2 - Forms with custom inputs that coming from different components

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm building angular 2 form with template driven and trying to re-use custom input which i made.

So i have one main components which that look like that:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" #f="ngForm">

        <custom-input></custom-input>

        <button class="btn btn-submit" [ngClass]="{disabled : !f.valid} ">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

The problem is that the UI work fine, and the input validation also works, **but** the custom input is not really a member of the form so I can't use the value of it in my onSubmit() method. also can't set the form as invalid when the input is invalid.

my custom input code looks like this:

custom-component.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.scss']
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the html looks like this:

---

```
  <div class="input-div">
  <input ngModel name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" #email="ngModel" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?">
  <span class="v" *ngIf="email.valid && email.touched"> 
                    &#10004;
                      </span>
  <span class="down-placeholder errormsg" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched && email.errors.required"> Please enter your email.  </span>
  <span class="down-placeholder errormsg" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched && email.errors.pattern"> Please enter a valid email. </span>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article is what you are looking for:

[How to Build Nested Model-driven Forms in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

There is an example about `FormGroup` and `FormBuilder` there should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your component ControlValueAccessor.

This article might help you:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

good luck!